# Is it possible to remove a tab from the Tridion GUI?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I would like to remove some tabs from the Tridion GUI for our editors.
For example the "Workflow" tab or the "E-mail Management" tab.
Is it possible to do this?
how? gui extention?

Thanks,

-JW

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily maintained through User Access

- Publication Properties

  - Security

    - Rights (`Workflow Management`)
- For the User Group (Example: ABC), don't give `Workflow Management` right
- Assign the Group (Example: ABC) to the User (Example: XYZ user)

If the user doesn't have access to workflow then he/she won't see the TAB.

Comment: I created a user with very limited rights that doesnt have any workflow management rights and still I see the "workflow" tab & "email Management" tab. Using 2011 SP1 btw.

Comment: @user883: on the publication properties, what are the rights selected for the user group?

Comment: This user only has "component management" rights on 1 publication.

Answer (score 2):

It’s possible to hide Ribbon Toolbar tabs from both JS API or from Editor configuration file. Taking into account requirement to hide tabs depending on user permissions, it’s only possibly to do from JS API. I don’t have example, but to create extension you have to do the following steps:

1. Create new extension Editor [doc](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D)
2. Create js file with functionality which will:

   2.1. Check current user permissions

```js
var user =                 $models.getItem(Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getInstance().getUserId());
// load user is not loaded and check permissions
```

2.2. Hide toolbar tab if needed

```
var toolbar = $controls.getControl(toolbarElement, “Tridion.Controls.RibbonToolbar”); // Where ‘toolbarElement’ – reference to toolbar root DOM element
toolbar.hideItem(“WorkflowPage”); // Where ‘WorkflowPage’ – ID of the DOM element of the Ribbon Tab you want to hide
```

3.. Created functionality in js file have to be executed after View being initialized:

```js
$evt.addEventListener($display, “start”, function() { … });
```

4.. Add this js file to corresponding view group as an extension.